# Check how many times a character occurs in a word (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I have an array that contains characters converted from a word via `.ToCharArray` method. I would like to check how many times a letter occurred in this array (word). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is a lookup:

```
Dim letterLookup = yourCharArray.ToLookup(Function(c) c)
' For example the letter e, note that it's case sensitive '
Dim eLetterCount As Int32 = letterLookup("e"c).Count()
```

This is efficient and has the advantage that you can even check letters which aren't contained in the `String`/`Char()`, you will get 0 as result.

By the way, you don't need to use `ToCharArray`, you could use this code on with original string.

If you wanted to list all contained letters:

```
Dim allLetters As IEnumerable(Of Char) = letterLookup.Select(Function(kv) kv.key)
```

If you wanted to ignore the case, so treat `e` and `E` as equal:

```
Dim letterLookup = yourCharArray.tolookup(Function(c) c, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

---

> For example the word 'tent'. The program would check which letter
>   occurs more than once (t) and find the position in the array (in this
>   case 0,3). It will also find the position in the array of the other
>   letters.

Then i would use a different approach also using LINQ:

```
Dim duplicateLetterPositions As Dictionary(Of Char,List(Of Integer)) = yourCharArray.
     Select(Function(c, index) New With {.Char = c, .Index = index}).
     GroupBy(Function(c) c.Char).
     Where(Function(grp) grp.Count > 1).
     ToDictionary(Function(grp) grp.Key, Function(grp) grp.Select(Function(x) x.Index).ToList())
```

Comment: How do I run a for loop through an 'IEnumerable' data type? e.g. I want to run a for loop to check the positions of the letters in the array that occur more than once.

Comment: @Moon: well, you could use `ToList` or `ToArray` to create a collection which can be iterated via index f.e. with a `For`-loop.

Comment: @Moon: What you want, if the letter `e` is contained 3 times you want 3  indexes?

Comment: For example the word 'tent'. The program would check which letter occurs more than once (t) and find the position in the array (in this case 0,3). It will also find the position in the array of the other letters. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @Moon: look at my edit